# Why is AVCaptureDevice.maxAvailableVideoZoomFactor so large?

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

On my iPad with a digital zoom of 5x, the reported captureDevice.maxAvailableVideoZoomFactor for the camera device is 153.
Shouldn't it be 5? Am I using the right property to get the max zoom factor?

Answer (score 1):

I found this from [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/2865758-maxavailablevideozoomfactor):

> On single-camera devices, this value is always equal to the device format’s videoMaxZoomFactor value. On a dual-camera device, the allowed range of video zoom factors can change if the device is delivering depth data to one or more capture outputs.

So if your iPad has dual/triple cameras and you are using [buildInDualCamera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/devicetype/2727142-builtindualcamera), etc. It can return a bigger max zoom level.